# enviar formulario a un controlador por Ajax Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-6

Ayuda!! estoy realizando un proyecto en Laravel versión 6 
cuando le coloco la action en el formulario si me llega al controlador pero si lo quiero enviar por ajax me sale el error.
Este formulario se encuentra en un modelo y tambien este formulario puede enviar archivos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi ajax

```
function subirTarea(){
 var formData = new FormData($('#material')[0]);

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{route("subirTarea")}}',
    data: formData,

    success: function(resultado) {
         console.log(resultado);
    },
})
```

}

mi controlador es

```
public function subirTarea(Request $request){
    return 'ok';
}
```

mi ruta es:

Route::post("subirTarea","Docentes\AsignaturaDocenteController@subirTarea")->name('subirTarea');

mi formulario es:

```
<form id="material" name="material" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" id="cod_peri" name="cod_peri" value="{{ $contenido['permiso'][0]->cod_peri }}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="cod_mate" name="cod_mate" value="{{ $contenido['permiso'][0]->cod_mate }}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="par_curs" name="par_curs" value="{{ $contenido['permiso'][0]->par_curs }}">
       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

        <table border="0" width=100% id="tbl_tarea">
            <tr id="adj_archivo">
                <div >
                    <th align="left">
                        <label>Seleccione el archivo que desee enviar con la tarea</label>
                    </th>
                    <th align="left">
                        <input type="file" name="archivo_tarea" id="archivo_tarea">
                    </th>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
<button id="guardar_material" onclick="subirTarea();"  class="md-btn md-btn-flat md-btn-flat-primary">Agregar Tarea</button></form>
```

Por Favor necesito ayuda

Comment: Para poderte ayudar necesitamos agregues el código del controlador, tu ruta y tu formulario así como el AJAX de paso nos aclares si trabajas con fetch o jquery o xmlHttpRequest

Comment: ¿no te falta la directiva dentro del form `@csrf` y posterior recuperarla en tu js y enviarla?

Comment: ya lo intente de esa manera como usted me indica pero tampoco me sale, por eso le coloque dentro del formulario un input y capturar por el ajax todo el formulario pero me sale el error de la img